# How to build C++ on a machine and execute on another?

Tags: c++, build, cross-platform

I'm sorry in advance if the question is a bit silly but it's the first time I face this problem and Google is not helping. Here's my problem: I have some C++ code that I build on my own PC (CMake as build system, Ubuntu 18.04 as OS) and it depends on other libraries such as Eigen, PCL and RapidJson. I would like to execute the same code on other reasonably similar machines (i.e. same OS, same architecture, and so on) where these libraries can't be installed, without rebuilding it from scratch. What is the "correct" way of doing this? Will just move the compiled binary suffice? Thank you.

Comment: That depends on how you are linking agains aforementioned libraries. If you are linking statically, you can just copy the binary. For dynamic linking, you would need to make sure those libraries are present on the target machine, using package manager of choice.

Comment: CMake has ExternalProject that can help with building dependencies from source: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)

Comment: There is also CPack that may help you bundle the binaries and the dependencies you built with CMake: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html)